# React Flatpicker is not picking current time

Tags: reactjs, flatpickr

Currently working on a attendance system and using react flatpickr to get user checkIn and checkout time flatpickr is getting current date but not getting current time. Here is my code.

```js
                <Flatpickr
                  data-enable-time
                  value={checkIn}
                  disabled={!isEmpty(id)}
                  onChange={date => this.handleDate(date, 'checkIn')}
                  placeholder="Check-in"
                  options={{
                    minDate: "today",
                    // dateFormat: "d-m-Y",
                    // enableTime: false,
                  }}
                  className={errors.checkIn ? "form-control is-invalid" : ""}
                />
                
                 handleDate = (dateObj, field) => {
    let date = dateObj && dateObj[0];
    this.setState({ [field]: date && moment.utc(date).format() });
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using native methods

Check this sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/flatpicker-with-current-time-6tg7j

```
    <Flatpickr
            ref={datepickerRef}
            options={options}
            value={""}
            onChange={(date, dateStr) => {
              let selectedDate = date[0];
              let currentDate = new Date();
              let currentTime = new Date(
                selectedDate.setHours(
                  currentDate.getHours(),
                  currentDate.getMinutes(),
                  currentDate.getSeconds()
                )
              );
              setDate(currentTime);
            }}
          />
```

Comment: Check the console post selection of date @user12660992